# Entity Framework MetadataWorkspace error

Tags: entity-framework-5, wcf-ria-services

Using a Code-First approach with Entity Framework 5 for a Silverlight to WCF RIA Services project. During solution build, I receive the following error and warning:

**Warning**
No persistent classes found. Is the metadata information missing?

**Error**
Failed to get the MetadataWorkspace for the DbContext type

I'm running off a local Database, and placed the custom connection string information in the constructor for the DbContext.

Comment: Klue, we need some more clues. What does the connection string look like? Looks like some third-party component is involved that expects metadata to be present at compile time, which would mean that you may have to switch to an EDMX approach.

Comment: Is it related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843467/wcf-ria-services-wizard-not-working-with-codefirst/13008680#13008680